# Graph the function $f(x)=|e^{-x+2}-1|$ without using graphing calculator.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Graph the function $f(x)=|e^{-x+2}-1|$ without using graphing calculator.

I tried so many times to solve it but $i$ was really confused because of the absolute value??

SO, Could you please tell the procedures that I should follow in graphing functions containing Absolute value like the one above

Comment: If you can get to the point of considering the effect of the absolute value, you are nearly done.  In general, $|f(x)|$ will "reflect" negative portions of the graph of $f$ vertically *over* the $x$-axis, effectively making any negative $y$-values positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Since $\;e^t\ge 1\iff t\ge0\;$ , we have that

$$e^{-x+2}-1\ge0\iff x\le 2$$ so

$$\left|e^{-x+2}-1\right|=\begin{cases}e^{-x+2}-1&,\;\;x\le 2\\{}\\1-e^{-x+2}&,\;\;x>2\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

procedure

a) Hm, $-x+2=(-(x-2))$ means a shift by 2 and a reflection

b) So now  I have an idea what $e^{-x+2}$ looks like

c) $-1$ ok, move it down one unit - got $e^{-x+2}-1$

d) absolute value...have to know where $f(x)=e^{-x+2}-1<0$ and draw the graph at these points  above the $x$-axis

Answer (score 0):

Try to break the problem:
1. plot exp(-x)
It would be like this:
[image]

2. multiply exp(-x) and exp(2) and plot:

[image]

3. subtract 1 from this on every point of the graph. Then, for -ve x, not much difference would be visible, as f(x) is very high valued. But for +ve x, as we go towards right, f(x) becomes -ve (which was not happening earlier).

[image]

4. now take absolute of this. For absolute:
   $$abs(x)=\begin{cases}-x&,\;\;x<0\\{}\\x&,\;\;x>0\end{cases}$$
   Hence, only the f(x) which was -ve in the above graph will go +ve. everything else remains same:

[image]

this will be the final graph.